# What is the difference between SFF-8482 and SFF-8082 connectors?

Tags: sas

A popular way to connect SAS hard drives to a SAS card having SFF-8087 sockets is to use a SFF-8087 to SFF-**8482** cable.

One can also find on the market SFF-8087 to SFF-**8082** cables, but I could find almost no documentation about the SFF-8**0**82 connector and it seems way less known.

At the beginning, I believed the 0 of 8082 was a typo, because there I could not find documentation about this connector type.
However, there is a specification: https://www.optcore.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/SFF-8082.pdf

Just wondering about what the SFF-8082 connector is, and its difference with SFF-8482.
Is the first an ancestor of the second?

Answer (score 1):

SFF-8482 is the standard connector on SAS drives, internal cables and backplanes:

[image]

[SFF-8082 Specification for
Labeling of Ports and Cable Assemblies](https://members.snia.org/document/dl/25818) does not define any connectors, just as you've found. Obviously, they made a mistake and likely wanted to refer to SFF-8**4**82.

Comment: Thanks. You seem to be right.The abstract of SFF-8082 shows that SAS is only one possible interface of this specification. SFF-8482 is about the SAS connector.